# Progress in Constructing $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am constructing $\mathbb{R}$ by taking the union of all Dedekind Cuts. However, I am facing some difficulties in the multiplication part. Here is my problem :

> We define multiplication as follow :
> $$
> AB=\{z\leq xy\;;x\in A,y\in B,z\in\mathbb{Q}\}
> $$
> With $x,y,A,B>0$. with $A$ and $B$ being two cuts in $\mathbb{R}$

Moreover, we define the following :

> $$
> [\alpha]=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}|x<\alpha\}\;\;\text{and}\;\;[\beta]=\{y\in\mathbb{Q}|y<\beta\}
> $$

**Problem** : Show that $[\alpha]\cdot[\beta]=[\alpha\cdot \beta]$ with $\alpha,\beta>0$

**My Attempt** : Recall that two sets $U$ and $V$ are equal if and only if $U\subseteq V$ and $V\subseteq U$. Therefore, I have proven first that $[\alpha]\cdot[\beta]\subseteq[\alpha\cdot \beta]$ by showing that for $x\in\alpha$ and $y\in\beta$, we have that since **$p,q>0$** then $x<\alpha$, $y<\beta$ implies that $xy<\alpha\cdot\beta$ which means $xy\in[\alpha\cdot \beta]$.

**My issue is proving the inverse implication that is $[\alpha\cdot \beta]\subseteq[\alpha]\cdot[\beta]$. I have given up.**

Answer (score 1):

I present a hint and a solution.

Hint: look at the complements of $[\alpha \beta]$ and $[\alpha][\beta]$. This would reverse your inverse statement.

Solution: The complement of $[\alpha][\beta]$ is the set of $z$ that is strictly greater than all elements of the form $xy$ with $x<\alpha$ and $y<\beta$. Lets take $x = \alpha - \delta$ and $y = \beta - \epsilon$. We must have $z > (\alpha - \delta)(\beta - \epsilon)$. Since this is true for all values of $\delta$ and $\epsilon$, we can take them to be arbitrarily small. This results in $z \geq \alpha \beta$. Hence $z$ is in the complement of $[\alpha \beta]$, which is your desired inverse.

Comment: I like your method, very intuitive.

Comment: On a separate note, you may have heard about people who don't really believe in the "real" numbers because of its "construction" via this method or the concept of completeness on the space of rational numbers. In my view, we have numbers for solving equations created by the four operations, which are solutions to polynomials (hence not including transcendental numbers), and we have numbers for geometry. In this case with the real line, we are looking at numbers geometrically, hence we are using concepts of limits. In the former view of numbers, the real numbers cannot be constructed.